# how to filter items from listbox?

Tags: c#-4.0

i want to filter items from listbox when i typed in combobox ..
suppose, when i type **"A"** in combobox then listbox display items which contains **"A"** anywhere.. **without using SQL STATEMENT...**

below is my code..

```
private void FillListBoxes()
{

        lbSearch.DisplayMember = "CatName";
        lbSearch.ValueMember = "catID";
        int count = FillList.Rows.Count;

        if (count > 0)
        {
            lbSearch.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {

                lbSearch.Items.Add(FillList.Rows[i]["CatName"].ToString());

            }

        }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold a list with all the items, assume `AllItems` is the name of this list. then you can try:

```
private void FillListBoxes() 
{
   string check=combobox1.Text;
   lbSearch.Items.Clear();
   foreach (string item in AllItems)
   {
        if (item.Contains(check);
         {
           lbSearch.Items.Add(item);
         } 
   }
}
```

Comment: you mean to say "Allitems " is a name of listbox or combobox or other datatable object ...???what....

Comment: please ans....Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.String'.